# Linkedin Api dynamic parameter passing

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, linkedin-api

I have a chrome extension and on its content script which runs at local host

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["lib/jquery.js", "searching_helper.js"],
    "matches": [ "http://localhost:8089/*"]
}]
```

In searching_helper.js I am getting the public profile url of linkedin members from another content script.

```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({u:true},function(response) {
console.log(response.ans);
linkedinProfileUrl = response.ans.profileUrl;
console.log('linkedinProfileUrl' + linkedinProfileUrl);
```

});

In linkedinProfileUrl variable I am getting the public profile url a linkedin profile being viewed.

Now what I want is that I have a server side code in which i have to give its url which is using linkedin api.

Server side code of 
index.html file

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
//here goes the api key, and the callback function
api_key: ******
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
authorize: true
 </script>
```

the function which runs on onload is defined in linkedin.js file

```
     function onLinkedInLoad() {
    onLinkedInLogin();
```

}

```
    //execute on login event
   function onLinkedInLogin() {
//pass user info to angular
angular.element(document.getElementById("appBody")).scope().$apply(
    function($scope) {
        $scope.getLinkedInData();
    }
);
```

}

and this getLinkedInData() method is defined in a controller .

```
    $scope.getLinkedInData = function() {
    if(!$scope.hasOwnProperty("userprofile")){
        IN.API.Profile("https://in.linkedin.com/in/latika").fields(
                [ "id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl",
                        "publicProfileUrl","positions","location","email-address"]).
```

In this IN.API.Profile("https://in.linkedin.com/in/latika") here I want to pass the linkedinProfileUrl got from the content script . and the problem is that if I pass parameters in index.html file it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer . I used localStorage to get the url.

In searching_helper.js used

```
localStorage.setItem('url', linkedinProfileUrl);
```

And then in linkedin.js used

```
  function onLinkedInLogin() {
var url = localStorage.getItem('url');
//pass user info to angular
angular.element(document.getElementById("appBody")).scope().$apply(
    function($scope) {

        $scope.getLinkedInData(url);
    }
);
```

}